# TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data with a variety of dtypes:

1. Restaurant ID           int64
2. Restaurant Name          object
3. Country Code              int64

...

20. Rating text              object
21. Votes                     int64
22. dtype: object

When I run the code below:

```
too_verbose_columns = (data.select_dtypes(include = 'O')\
    .columns[data.select_dtypes(include='O').nunique() > 2]\  
    .tolist())
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is this pandas? If not, what library are you using?

Comment: yes, this is Pandas

Comment: `non-string sequence` means any type which is a sequence except for `str` (and sometimes `bytes`). Given most of the examples of `df.select_types` look like `df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'int64'])` (i.e., types in a list), you should probably be using a list instead of a string

Comment: I still get this error If I change to 'object'

Comment: Do you mean `include=['O']` or `include='object'` or `include=['object']`?

Comment: second one include='object'

Comment: I think you need to change this to `include=['object']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pandas pre-v0.21

The string `'O'` is not considered a sequence. You need to input, for example, a list. In addition, there's no need to repeat the call to `select_dtypes`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '2', '4'], ['5', '6', '7']],
                    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

df = data.select_dtypes(include=['O'])

too_verbose_columns = df.columns[df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) > 2].tolist()

print(too_verbose_columns)

['col1', 'col3']
```

`col2` is out of scope since it only has 2 unique elements.

### Pandas v0.21+

As of Pandas v0.21, `select_dtypes` [now accepts a scalar](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210):

> [DataFrame.select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes) now accepts scalar values for
> include/exclude as well as list-like. ([GH16855](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16855))